# How to delete unknown number last record (on condition)?

Tags: mysql

Could you please tell me how to delete unknown number last record (on condition)?

For example, in this situation I want to delete record with id: 6 to 10.

Note: this table and records is not constant.

```
+----+-----+---------+
| id | url | emailid |
+----+-----+---------+
|  1 |  10 |       1 |
|  2 |  20 |       0 |
|  3 |  30 |       2 |
|  4 |  40 |       0 |
|  5 |  50 |      10 |
|  6 |  60 |       0 |
|  7 |  70 |       0 |
|  8 |  80 |       0 |
|  9 |  90 |       0 |
| 10 | 100 |       0 |
+----+-----+---------+
```

Thanks...

Comment: you question is still not clear what you mean by not constant

Comment: not constant !!! is it type of varchar ? What do you mean ?

Comment: @SanketPipariya Excuse my bad english! this table and records is not constant.

Comment: @Daniyal i have edited my question, is this the case?

Comment: @AbdulBasit thanks for your attention, No 6-10 is not constant, They can be 7-11 or 8-15 or 9-10 or ...

Comment: but you can change the variable values by calling in a function or something $start and $end can be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to delete the last set of records where all the values are `0`.  This is a bit of a pain.  You can find the minimum such id as:

```
select min(t.id)
from table t
where t.emailid = 0 and
      not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id > t.id and t2.emailid <> 0);
```

The logic is:  find all rows where `emailid` is 0 and there are no subsequent emailids that are not zero.

You can put this into a `delete` using `join`:

```
delete t
    from table t cross join
         (select min(t.id) as first0id
          from table t
          where t.emailid = 0 and
                not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id > t.id and t2.emailid <> 0)
         ) tmin
     where t.id >= tmin.first0id;
```

Comment: Tanks for your answer, this query delete just one row, I want to delete all 6-10 row.

Comment: @Daniyal . . . Logic inversion.  That should be `<> 0` in the subquery, not `= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `between` keyword in your query like this

```
delete from yourtable where id BETWEEN 6 AND 10
```

Comment: 6 to 10 is not constant!

Comment: @Daniyal - is it numeric right ? what's data type of id column?

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
  delete from your_table where id between 6 AND 10
```

for not being constant you can first store start and end values in variable and then pass in query,example(in php)

```
 $start = 6 ;
 $end = 10;
```

query

```
   "delete from your_table where id between $start AND $end"
```